# Filtering a js query with the style

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html table element in which I hide all tr and I want to get all hide tr elements with this query :

```
document.querySelectorAll("tr[style='display: none']");
```

But this query returns a empty List and I don't understand why. Is my selection is wrong or it isn't possible to get tr element like that ?

Thanking in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('tr[style*="display: none"]');
```

Comment: @A.F.K, why do you think so? I check this in Google Chrome, works fine.

Comment: It needs the spaces to be exact, I guess.

Comment: With the space, it's working perfectly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector seems correct to me. Anyway it will retrieve all the `TR` elements that exactly matches the style attribute.
Eg:

```
<tr style='display: none'>[...]</tr>
```

is ok **but**

```
<tr style='display: none; background-color: red'>[...]</tr>
```

will not be retrieved.

Please consider to add a class to the relevant tags

Answer (score 0):

In case your element has multiple styles, you could use:

```
var elements = [];
var temp = document.querySelectorAll('tr[style]');
for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    if (temp[i].style.display == 'none')
        elements.push(temp[i]);
}
```